# Determining Affine Transformation Parameters?

Tags: qgis, vector, affine-transformation

I am trying to use the qgsAffine plugin to do the transformation but I have no idea in its usage.

- How to find the transformation parameters? I found some posts suggest using the OpenJump
- How to use the plug-in? I found my plug-in UI does not match with my found in Google. Why?

Here is my coordinates:

- Original x 0.3704 (EPSG:4326) to Target long 114.2031
- Original y 0.52804 (EPSG:4326) to Target lat 22.3249

[image: Here is my QGIS Affine plug-in]